# Issue with AJAX and jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Ajax</title> 
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 

function register()
{ 
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://exampleurl.com/api/index.php",
    data: "action=login_user&app_key=MyAPIKey&username=Bob&password=HisPassword",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) 
         {
                    alert(data);
         }
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
         {
                    alert(errorThrown);
         }
          });
}
</script> 

</head> 
<body> 
<form>      
<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="register()"/>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

The URL returns a string (plain-text) when used in the address bar. Why is the above code not working? When I click on the button, I get no alert. Basically, nothing happens.

Browsers tried: IE 8 and Chrome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you requesting a URL from a different domain? That won't work.

Comment: @Matt, you can do ajax gets, but not posts. How do you think people embed third party feeds in their sites.

Comment: @Jeremy: since when? http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/gptjD/1/

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an exception being thrown in the `$.ajax` call.

Consider

1. ensuring your URI is well formed by taking the query parameters out of the URL and supplying a `data` object instead:

   `data: {
     action: login_user,
     app_key: ....
     etc
   }`
2. adding an `error` handler too

Comment: pop up Chrome's developer tools (ctrl-shift-J under windows) and look for any exceptions being thrown.  And use the object literal notation shown above for 'data:', rather than a string!

Comment: just tried using developer tools. The request is being made. This is what I see in the console: GET <URL> Undefined and also XMLHttpRequest cannot load <URL> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1):

Is example.com the URL of your local site? If not, your above example violates [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can circumvent this by doing the call through a proxy on the server side.

Comment: no it's not local. So, how do I get a response string from a URL? I am passing the username, pass and my API key in the URL.

Comment: @Meow: what's the API you're using?

Comment: If its not local the far end will either need to be configured to work with a JSONP request or the http request will have to come from the server side rather than the client. What are you using on the server side?

Comment: @Matt Ball, you need to be logged in to see the API. So, here is the screenshot - http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ff9ta8b7. I want to use the API to write a Chrome Extension. You pointed to me to jQuery two days back. I am really new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: you forgot an `,` after the success function

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to separate the data ?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://exampleurl.com/api/index.php",
    data: "action=login_user&app_key=MyAPIKey&username=Bob&password=BobPassword",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thrd, tried separating the parameters and the URL. Still no alert.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access over the backend url?

You might need to declare the contentType.  You might also need to do a post and set the data.

```
data: "{ 'action': 'login_user', 'app_key': 'MyAppKey', etc. }"
```

Comment: I am really new to web development. When I type in the URL in my address bar, I get a new page with just one line of plain-text. This is the authentication code for the user log-in. So, the URL is working. Just have to pass the username, pass, API key as parameters and get the response text.